# Fast search and SharePoint search

Tags: search, fast-search, fast

I have an issue with a SharePoint farm, it has both SharePoint Search and Fast Search configured.  When SharePoint Search is configured on its own, search indexes everything in around 20 minutes, as soon as fast search is in the mix crawls take inordinate amounts of time to complete.

As its a shared farm I was hoping that one set of apps could have SharePoint Search and others would use Fast search.  Is this a possible scenario and more importantly is it a supported solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Each Search service application is either the Standard SharePoint Search or the Fast Connector/Query. Just separate them into their own service applications, and you should just configure the web applications to use two different sets of service connections, one including FAST and excluding sharepoint search, and the other using sharepoint search and excluding FAST.

This is in: CA -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> Service Connections

It will be supported since FAST isn't a third party solution, and you aren't touching SQL.